# MSSQL Select entries from 2 joined table specified between rows

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have 2 Tables on my Server.
One is storing Fileinformations (Root, Name, UserID, Size..)
another one is storing the E-Mail Address for each UserID.

I want to select all entries between 2 specified Rows (eg. ordered by File Size from Table1)

My Code:

```
select TOP 16 * from 
(
select Row_Number() over (order by [Table1].[File Size]) as RowIndex,
* from (SELECT Table1.*,Table2.[E-Mail]
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID 
ORDER BY Table1.[File Size])as joined
) 
as Sub
Where Sub.RowIndex >= 20
```

For Example Select first 16 Entries after Row 20 from the JOIN Order by `File Size`

Error:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

What can I do?
This Query is used to display first 16 entries for more than 100k entries for virtualization datagridview of c#..

Comment: Is this in VB? If so, why `c#`?

Comment: Sample data and expected output will be more helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `ORDER BY Table1.[File Size]` from inner query

```
select TOP 16 * from 
(
select Row_Number() over (order by [Table1].[File Size]) as RowIndex,
* from (SELECT Table1.*,Table2.[E-Mail]
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table1.UserID = Table2.UserID 
)as joined
) 
as Sub
Where Sub.RowIndex >= 20
ORDER BY Table1.[File Size]
```

Comment: Thanks! But I also had to remove [Table1] from the first order.